# Choosing a data structure for a group of static (almost) thousands of objects on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas, data-structure

I have this requirement to implement a data structure for a group of thousands of displayable objects, on HTML5 canvas. Something like a particle system. The objects are randomly spread on the map. They have different colors and sizes. Each of them can be removed and I can also add more objects onto the map. These objects may move around a little bit but just one or two pixels. But on any specific (x,y) position there can be only one object.

So we can say that these are static objects. To render this group of objects and make changes to them I have used a particle system and put all the objects in an array. It works but the performance isn't good especially if I perform some operations on the objects. I find that each time I need to find or remove a particular object at a specific location I have to loop through the entire array, which is not very efficient.

Now my question is, can I put the objects into an object and use their position on the map as the key, and the object itself as the value? This way it works more like a hashmap or dictionary. So each time I want to get an object based on its location I can complete that operation in O(1) time. Removing any of the objects is also very easy too. When adding new object I just need to check if the location is occupied otherwise I put the new object in a new position. This way looks so good I want to implement it right away. In `ES6` javascript maybe I will put them into Map or WeakMap. But before I do that I want to know if there is any drawback for this method or is it even a good option for this situation? I am also gonna implement this on the game server and transmit the data through network. I wonder if this method has any negative effect on networking?

Comment: Yes, you can. And I don't think any form of structure would have any effect on networking; it just depends on how well you write your networking code.

Comment: As for using a particle system, the whole point of such a system is to update the positions and effects and colours and whatever on every object on every frame. Easier to use an array in that case, isn't it? Or some sort of hash, as you've described.